# I have an office excel add-in for which SSO enabled with an azure AD application. The add-in works locally but not when hosted on higher environment

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins

I have an office excel add-in where I have updated manifest for getting access token from azure ad application. local manifest.xml looks like below. Note for this I have dedicated azure application and application id is there in ID and Resource.

[Local manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFy9g.png)

I am able to get token when calling like below
let token: string = await Office.auth.getAccessToken({
});

Now, I have dedicated application for QA with same configuration. Only reply url and Authority URI is different since it should contain fully qualified domain name there. Below is QA manifest.xml
[QA manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMuwk.png)

I am not able to get token with same piece of code. Following error response I'm getting while that getAccessToken called.

[Error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3F52.png)

I searched for last 7 days in everywhere, but not any fruitful fixes found. Can anyone please help me.

I tried with adding below detail in manifest.xml
[IdentityAPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p56Q0.png)

But still no luck.

Comment: @DevJ I saw one comment you have given in other thread asking for this error code. Can you please check this one.